# Deprecated function set_cookie

Tags: comments, cookies

I am running EE 6.2.1. My developer log continuously reports two errors:

> Deprecated function set_cookie() called in
> /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/systemfolder/ee/ExpressionEngine/Addons/comment/mod.comment.php
> on line 1738.
>
> Deprecated since 2.8. Use EE_Input::delete_cookie() instead.

and

> Deprecated function set_cookie() called in
> /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/systemfolder/ee/ExpressionEngine/Addons/comment/mod.comment.php
> on line 1728.
>
> Deprecated since 2.8. Use EE_Input::delete_cookie() instead.

How could I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that will be fixed with 6.2.4 - see [Github #1759](https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/pull/1759)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking that the files got updated properly. Looking at the codebase for 6.2.1, the referenced lines do not contain `set_cookie` function mentioned: https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/blob/5b36e9d84ba183ef863747dbb7df16b56644a83e/system/ee/ExpressionEngine/Addons/comment/mod.comment.php#L1738

Comment: The two files on my server and the one you quote are identical, I already compared them. In the one on Github you find `ee()->input->set_cookie('notify_me', 'no');` in line 1729. So the deprecated methods are in the codebase (and I wonder why nobody else recognizes/complains this).

Comment: This might be something specific to the PHP version you're using. Can you file this as bug report on https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/issues ?

Comment: Ok, so I did right now!